# Way to restrict the number of times a value can appear in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I have a play database that I try things in and have come up with a situation where I have a table that has a foreign key in it.  I want to limit the number of times a specific value from that other table can appear in this table.  I want the 'local' table to accept any value from that foreign table, but only to a maximum of four times.  I think this can be done with a trigger, but would like to know if there is some sort of other constraint or check that can be placed to enforce this rule.  The reason is that the objects I'm describing can have a maximum of four descriptors associated and I don't want four columns in the main table for keeping track as not every item will reach that limit; in fact, I believe most won't ever have two.

Comment: Trigger will do. There are other options by using composite key and restricting values in second column. But in that case value increment in 2nd column should be maintained at business layer.

Comment: I agree with the trigger.  You can put a check constraint on the table that calls a function, but that's not ideal.  You could also just write a stored procedure with the logic in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a check constraint with a user defined function.
There are two benefits of this over using triggers:

1. This is what check constraints are designed for.
2. Using Triggers would require an instead of insert and instead of update triggers, resulting in a much longer code, that's harder to write and maintain.

Here is a quick example:

Create test table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Col1 int
)
GO
```

Create the validation function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsValueAllowed
(
    @Value int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test WHERE Col1 = @Value) > 4 RETURN 0

RETURN 1

END
GO
```

Add the check constraint to the table

```
ALTER TABLE Test
    ADD CONSTRAINT ck_RestrictCol1 CHECK (dbo.IsValueAllowed(Col1) = 1)
GO
```

Tests:

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES 
(1), (1), (1), (1),
(2), (2), (2)

INSERT INTO Test VALUES (2)

SELECT *
FROM Test

INSERT INTO Test VALUES (1) -- This will fail with an error message: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_RestrictCol1"
```

[see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/UTGPA77505)